# ortp library in configure and install mediastreamer2 library

Tags: configure, rtp

I want to make and install mediastreamer2 library and I've installed libortp-dev library.

but after executing `./configure` in mediastreamer2 folder, I encountered this error:

```
configure: error: Couldn't find ortp library
```

I don't know why!?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem!
The problem was version of ortp library.

libortp library's version in ubuntu repository is 0.16

and mediastreamer need this library in version 0.22.

I've realized that by manipulating configure file.